# VBA: Select rows based on variable - compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to dynamically select rows based on the values in cells A5 and A6.

When I run the macro I'm getting 'Compile Error: Object Required'

```
Sheets("Employees").Select
    Dim var1 As String
    Set var1 = Worksheets("Time Stamp").Range("A5")
    Dim var2 As String
    Set var2 = Worksheets("Time Stamp").Range("A6")
    ws.Rows(var1 & ":" & var2).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Set var1 = Worksheets("Time Stamp").Range("A5")
```

should be

```
var1 = Worksheets("Time Stamp").Range("A5")
```

`Set` is only used when assigning value to object-type variables, and `String` is not an object type

Comment: Ah! I knew it was probably that, but thanks for explicitly stating you use `Set` for objects. I knew it was definitely for `Ranges`, but was always left guessing when using other variables until the "compiler" notified me of the error. :D  (...and now that I look at it, the error message tells me this. I should pay more attention, d'oh).

Comment: The difference between the two statements would be much more obvious without the implicit default member call, i.e. `var1 = Worksheets("Time Stamp").Range("A5").Value`, which makes the `Set` keyword much more blatantly superfluous.